# How to search in ElasticSearch the most common word of a single field in a single document?

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, kibana

How to search in ElasticSearch the most common word of a single field in a single document? Lets say I have a document that have a field "pdf_content" of type keyword containing:

"good polite nice good polite good"

I would like a return of

```
{
    word: good,
    occurences: 3
},
{
    word: polite,
    occurences: 2
},
{
    word: nice,
    occurences: 1
},
```

How is this possible using ElasticSearch 7.15?

I tried this in the Kibana console:

```
GET /pdf/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "pdf_contents": {
      "terms": { "field": "pdf_content" }
    }
  }
}
```

But it only returns me the list of PDFs i have indexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you ever tried [term_vector](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html?)?:

Basically, you can do:

Mappings:

```json
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "pdf_content": {
                "type": "text",
                "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets_payloads"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with your sample document:

```json
POST /pdf/_doc/1

{
    "pdf_content": "good polite nice good polite good"
}
```

Then you can do:

```json
GET /pdf/_termvectors/1

{
  "fields" : ["pdf_content"],
  "offsets" : false,
  "payloads" : false,
  "positions" : false,
  "term_statistics" : false,
  "field_statistics" : false
}
```

If you want to see other information, you can set them to `true`. Set all to `false` give you what you want.

Comment: Please note that you cannot use type `keyword`, because it will be indexed the full string. It means when you want to see the term vector, it will give you the full string that occurs once. If you really want to use keyword, you can create another field called `raw` within your `pdf_content` and calculate the term_vector on that field.

Comment: Thank you, it is what I was looking for!